# Input box having error with submit for ranging numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a made a dynamic input boxes that changes value depending on what the user put.. basically **win chance** ranges from **0.01% to 98%** and the **payout/multiplier** ranges from **1.0102 to 9900** 
So the problem is when I submit it tells to enter valid value, while they are valid... because I put JS code to not allow any other numbers below or high than that.

```
<div class="form">



  <form action="/" method="post">



     <div class="top-row">
      <div class="field-wrap">
      <label class="active">
            Win Chance
          </label>

        <input id="winc" value="49.5" type="number" min="0" max="98" onkeyup="wc(this);" />
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
      <label class="active">
            Payout
          </label>
        <input id="payc" value="2" type="number" min="0" max="9900" onkeyup="pc(this)"   />
      </div>
    </div>



    <button type="submit" class="button">Get Started</button>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMbPGa?editors=1010

JS code

```
  function wc(input) {
    if (input.value < 0.01) input.value = 0.01;
    if (input.value > 98) input.value = 98;
    y = 99 / input.value;

    document.getElementById("payc").value = y;
  }

  function pc(input) {
    if (input.value < 1.0102) input.value = 1.0102;
    if (input.value > 9900) input.value = 9900;
    x = 99 / input.value;

    document.getElementById("winc").value = x;
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant JS code directly in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is input type `number` here is only accepting integer value, not decimals. That's why it is throwing the error.

The best way to do this is, use the input type as `text` and validate it through JavaScript or JQuery if its between the defined range. So, your code will be as follows:

```
<div class="form">
  <form action="/" method="post">
     <div class="top-row">
      <div class="field-wrap">
      <label class="active">
            Win Chance
          </label>

        <input id="winc" value="49.5" type="text" onkeyup="wc(this);" />
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
      <label class="active">
            Payout
          </label>
        <input id="payc" value="2" type="text" onkeyup="pc(this)"   />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Get Started</button>
```

Alternate way, You can add an attribute `step` to input type `number` to make it accept decimals. This is not a tested method with your scenario.

Comment: *"input type number only accepts integer, not decimals."* - That's not true.